# Unity can't drop image in slot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner in Unity.I have wrote this in my code

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
........
public Image gun_image;
```

I want to assign this image from unity , so I tried to drag and drop my image in the gun_image slot from the inspector.This is the image:[image]

And this is the inspector:

[image]

(bullets image is something else).Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Select the asset in the project view so that the inspector window shows its properties. Make sure `Texture Type` is set to `Sprite (2D and UI)`.

If you need to use the image as a normal texture as well then leave it at Default and instead change your `Image` reference to a `Texture`. Then in your canvas remove the Image and instead use a RawImage.

Answer (score 0):

[`Image`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) is a **Component** type. You rather mean [`Texture2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html) or [`Sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Sprite.html) which are asset types.

And set the texture via the [Import Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html) to `Texture Type` = [Sprite(2D and UI)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextureTypes.html#Sprite)